# Possible cardinalities of spherical tiling

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, finite-groups, tiling

Suppose that we have a tiling of $n$-dimensional (I want to get answer for $n = 4$, but general result would be nice!) sphere by isometric tiles strictly contained inside the right-angled simplex. What is the set of possible numbers of tiles? There is an obvious restriction on the highest prime divisor coming from Jordan number of $SO(n)$, but is it the only real one?

Comment: Interesting question. What is this Jordan number?